# Media library not working with wp_editor() on the front end

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, media-library, front-end, wp-editor

**Very related**: [Add Media has stopped working in the front end since 4.5 update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224139/add-media-has-stopped-working-in-the-front-end-since-4-5-update)

I want to run the `wp_editor()` function to load the classic WordPress editor on the Front-End.

I need to do this out of the WordPress theme, so I am loading WordPress manually:

```
require_once("../wp-load.php");
```

And that allows me to use the `wp_editor()` function, with some custom settings.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

$settings = array(
'wpautop' => true,
'media_buttons' => true,
'textarea_name' => 'contenido',
'textarea_rows' => 12,
'tabindex' => '',
'editor_css' => '',
'editor_class' => '',
'teeny' => false,
'dfw' => false,
'tinymce' => true,
'quicktags' => true
);

wp_editor( '' /* Empty content */, 'contenido' /* ID */, $settings );
```

I am also logging in the user as follows:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 

if( $user ) {
    $curr_user = new WP_User( $user_id , $user->user_login ); 
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
}
```

I am loading the required scripts and styles in the `head` section of the DOM. (Do you know if I am missing something, does the order matter?)

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'underscore' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-util' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'thickbox' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'thickbox' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'editor' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'quicktags' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'buttons' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wplink' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-fullscreen-stub' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'media-upload' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-embed' );

_WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts(false);
_WP_Editors::editor_js();

wp_print_scripts();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

But the media button is not working (it shows and reacts to the click event but it does not open the modal on click).

**Console error says (when clicking the Insert Media button)**:

> TypeError: i is undefined at underscore.min.js

I digged in the source code and i seems to be referencing the data-editor attribute.

But, at least in the DOM, it is correctly defined.

Maybe I am missing an important script in my queue?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this outside of WordPress?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thanks for your time. Yes, the reason is because this is part of an additional Admin Panel (not a substitute for WP Admin) which is already created and cannot easily be integrated into the current WordPress theme. A small group of users should be using this simple interface to send posts (without featured images, slugs... just the post itself). Those posts will be programatically saved as pending.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this script https://github.com/anteprimorac/js-wp-editor.

This can be used to add WordPress editor php: wp_editor()

Comment: Thank you, but this is useful if I want to add the editor to my current theme and using AJAX. I want to do it out of wordpress and without AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_enqueue_media()` function to ensure that the required scripts and styles are enqueued

```
function enqueue_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_media();
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts');


$content = $_POST['contenido'];

$settings = array(
'wpautop' => true,
'media_buttons' => true,
'textarea_name' => 'contenido',
'textarea_rows' => 12,
'tabindex' => '',
'editor_css' => '',
'editor_class' => '',
'teeny' => false,
'dfw' => false,
'tinymce' => true,
'quicktags' => true
);

wp_editor($content, 'contenido', $settings);
```